Why cant I change the position of the canvas tag in my html file?
I want to center the canvas


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function init() {
            console.log("Hello world!");
            draw();
        }

        function draw() {
            var myCanv = document.getElementById("can");
            const rctngl = myCanv.getContext("2d");

            rctngl.fillStyle = "yellow";
            rctngl.strokeRect(19, 19, 42, 42);
            rctngl.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">

<h1 style="text-align: center">Basic Partical System</h1>
    <br />
    <br />

    <canvas id="can" width="300" height="200" style="border:1px solid gray" >

    </canvas>

    <br />

     <button type="button">Change Spawn Color</button>

    <br />
    <p>
        Frame Count: 0
    </p>
    <p>
        Rectangle Count: 0
    </p>
    


</body>
</html>



I am have no idea where I am making a mistake. or if canvas can even be moved. Any help would be appreciated
after trying these in the canvas tag:
position: relative;
position: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-left: 100px;

Nothing has changed and it stays on the left of the page and will not move at all.

You seem to have tried to set the left margin and the position property, but you didn't give it position coordinates. position: center isn't valid CSS. Have you checked the documentation?

when i put margin-left: 50% on the canvas, it moves it over 50% of the width.
